# How to include Hsql database in WAR File?

Tags: java, war, hsqldb

i am developing a little application in JAVA, in which i use HSQL database to store some statistics and perform some calculations, now the requirement of application is like

- The web application should be packaged as a self-contained portable war file. The war should contain any/all 3rd party jars that it depends on.
- It should be possible to download a fresh tomcat, install the war, and use web app immediately without any configuration.
- All config parameters should have useful default values.

i have developed the application but i am not able to include thw HSQL database in WAR file, i have tried different tutorials and search on stack overflow but i can't find any solution,

please tell me the way how i include hsql database in war file ?

Comment: No particular experience with HSQL, but in general one _creates_ the database on the fly. Filling it with initial tables and values using a read-only SQL script one dumped from an existing DB. Or using JPA. The war itself should be regarded as read-only resources.

Answer (score 1):

Create a java class that create `HSQL` database on tomcat start if not exist 
path of `HSQL` database for exemple tomcat/conf:

```
Server server = new Server();
server.setDatabaseName(0, "test");
server.setDatabasePath(0, "file:/path/to/db");
server.start();
```

Comment: where i place hsql database folder in my war file ? and how to start runServer.bat file to run hsql server on running war file ? it is my url for connecting hsql database jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/

Comment: The war file contains static code and resources. You can include the hsqldb.jar like any other jar. The actual database folder is your data. It cannot go into the war file unless the data is completely read-only and is packaged as a separate jar.